# MicroPython Socket sends strings without encoding

Tags: string, sockets, raspberry-pi4, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to write code which runs a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Pico.  The only problem has been with the socket library.  On the Pico this works:

```
cl.send("<p>Clock: " + strClk + "</p>")
```

On the Raspberry Pi 4 it is necessary to do something like:

```
cl.send(str.encode("<p>Clock:" + chr(32) + strClk + "</p>"))
```

Simple strings can be dealt with by casting:

```
cl.send(b"<p>Clock</p>"
```

It seems that the Pico is treating strings as bytearrays.  Any suggestions about how to handle this gratefully appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what suggestions you're looking for; it sounds like you already solved the problem.

Comment: A syntax such as b'string' works on both the Pi 4 and the Pico which solves the compatibility problem.  However, does this give the Pico an extra task?

Answer (score 2):

In regular Python, the socket `send` method requires a byte string. According to the [MicroPython documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send), the requirement is the same:

> `socket.send(bytes)`
>
> Send data to the socket. The socket must be connected to a remote socket. Returns number of bytes sent, which may be smaller than the length of data (“short write”).

It looks like MicroPython will also accept a string argument, but in this case it's unclear exactly what you're transmitting (does the string get encoded to utf-8? To something else?), so I would just avoid that and in both MicroPython and Python always encode your strings to byte:

```py
cl.send(f"Clock: {strClk}".encode())
```

That will do the correct thing in both Python implementations.